# Select word from string based on conditions

Tags: php, sql, function

I'm currently attempting to select a specific word from a string based on surrounding conditions. Specifically, I'd like to select a word from a MySQL Query.

For example:

1. Select the word/words that is in surrounded by tildes (`): I am an `apple` -> apple;
2. SELECT `data` FROM `tableName` -> data -OR- {"data", "tableName"}; (I mostly need to output "data", but I can work around if I have to select everything in tildes.)

I have a query function that currently needs 2 parameters (to make it simpler to store database values in variables).

```
function MysqlQuery($query, $find)
{
    $query = MysqlQueryWild($query);
    $fetch = $query->fetch_array();
    // Used to run a standard select query.
    return $fetch[$find];
}
```

I'd like to chop it down to only needing one parameter, the query, and automatically selecting the column within the function with the above method.

Closest I got was this:

```
function MysqliQuery($query)
{
    preg_match('"([^\\`]+)"', $query, $result);
    $query = MysqlQueryWild($query);
    $fetch = $query->fetch_array();
    // Used to run a standard select query.
    return $fetch[$result[0]];
}
```

But it selects the word "SELECT" which is NOT encased by tildes.

Comment: can u give example how your table looks like and the data that exist in there?

Comment: @BilhasryRamadhony The function is to pull data from any table with any type of data. The important part is the structure of the query which is usually SELECT `data` FROM `tableName`; And I would like to output "data" and "tableName" as they're in tildes.

Answer (score 0):

In sql you can use the keyword "Like" to find entries with specified conditions. % is used to represent 0-inf characters and _ represents 1 character. So for your example this is the select query you want.

SELECT 'data'

FROM 'table name'

WHERE 'column name' LIKE '`%`';

So for your case just use this query instead of trying to get all the words and manually find the ones surrounded by tildes